# Natural boundary of holomorphic function on a bounded set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be a bounded and connected open subset of the complex plane. Show that there exists $f \in H(D)$ which cannot be extended to a function holomorphic in a strictly larger connected open set.

My strategy so far has been to show that there exists a set $E \subset D$ such that $E$ has no limit point in $D$ but every point of $\partial D$ is a limit point of $E$. But, I'm not sure how to show that such a $E$ indeed exists. Even when I do show that such an $E$ exists, how do I show that $f$ cannot be extended in the way described above? Is there any way to use the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem in this context?

Comment: Not approximation but [factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem#Existence_of_entire_function_with_specified_zeroes).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $$f(z)=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{2^{-k}}{z-a_k} $$

where $\{a_k,k\ge 1\}$ is a dense subset of $\partial D$.

It converges locally uniformly in $D$ so it is analytic.

Then write $D=\bigcup_j D_j$ where each $D_j$ is simply connected open. Let $F_j(z)$ be a primitive of $f$ analytic on $D_j$, you'll get that $$\Re(F_j(z))= C_j+\sum_{k\ge 1} 2^{-k}\log|z-a_k|$$ which $\to -\infty$ as $z\to a_k$.

None of the $F_j$ is analytic at $a_k$, so $f$ can't be analytic anywhere on $\partial D$.